# Get dimensions from text in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks similar to this:

```
tumblr_mgn6mfe9aD1rbaz5bo1_500.jpg (JPEG Image, 500 × 705 pixels)
```

I want to strip the text until I get the value 500 & 705. I want them as two separate values. How can I do this in javascript?

Comment: Will the string always be in this exact format?

Comment: yes they will be in the exact format but different values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var match = /(\d+) × (\d+) pixels\)$/.exec('tumblr_mgn6mfe9aD1rbaz5bo1_500.jpg (JPEG Image, 500 × 705 pixels)')
```

Then `match[1]` and `match[2]` will contain the two values you are looking for (as strings).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can match the dimension:

```
var result = (/(\d+)\s*(×|x)\s*(\d+)\s*pixels\)$/g).exec('tumblr_mgn6mfe9aD1rbaz5bo1_500.jpg (JPEG Image, 500 × 705 pixels)');
console.log(result[1]); //"500"
console.log(result[3]); //"705"
```